# How are these 2 Water Source Heat Pump units wired to a single Thermostat?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

This is a brand new construction, 13 floor apartment building in Manhattan. I am trying to replace the stock thermostats with the new Ecobee. 3 rooms were easy but the larger living area has 2 of these https://www.waterfurnace.com/commercial/products/water-source-geothermal-heat-pumps/versatec-300.

Both of these are connected to a single thermostat. Ecobee says thye don't work with 2 units.

So I removed the old thermostat to see what wires were connected on that side and also traced the wiringn back to each WSHP unit.

This is the old thermostat and the wiring. It looks like all the wiring is doubled up. This would be problematic in many ways getting power from 2 different transformers etc but it looks like some of those wires are not connected to anything on the other side on the second unit with the extra card. One red isn't being used

[image: Old Thermostat]
[image: Old Wiring]

So I traced it back to the unit. The first one looks like a normal setup. That's how all the other individual units are wired to a single thermostat and working properly. Except that the Blue wire is not connected to the thermostat.

[image]

So now I traced the wires back again to the second unit and things get more interesting. There are only 4 wires that get used and they are going into a card and I am trying to figure out what this card actually does. I believe it has some signficance to the problem at hand. Only the Black, Orange, Yellow and Green wires are used. Red White and Blue are unused.

This is what the PINs say:

```
24V/Common Black
E/W2 Yellow
Y Orange
O Green
```

[image]
[image]

This is how the card on this unit looks like.

[image]

Another thing is that my neighbor has the exact same apt with the 2 units and he doubled up the wires on the ecobee and it has been working fine. His is the previous generation. Not sure if that matters.

I don't know anything about HVAC units so seeing if anyone here can point me in the right direction. The building folks kept saying it's daisy-chained but I am not sure they know what they are talking about.

A few questions:

- How is this working?
- Why is the blue wire unused? It's connected on every other Thermostat in the Apt to Y2 which is second stage cooling?
- What is this extra card? I think retrozone.com used to make it. I have only found 1 reference to it in the context of dual fuel.
- Can this work with the Ecobee if just double the wires. It's working for my neighbor. I have been reading about twinning boards etc that people use for this sort of thing and I am just completely lost.